# Do we need to sanitize data when a stored procedure is used?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-injection

I'm pretty sure the answer is this is no but better to ask now than to ask for forgiveness...

My understanding is that a SQL injection typically happens when we create a query in serverside code and run it directly against the database as so:

```
db.any('SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE id = '${bar}')
```

However if we are using stored procedures, is it always safe?  My understanding (and from what I've been able to find searching for the topic) is that as long as we are using proper types, it is because if we use

```
db.any('SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE id = $1', [bar])
```

A type cast will be thrown if bar is not a type matching the column id.  What if id was a character varying or text field though and we did something like this:

```
const bar = "1'; DROP TABLE users;"; 
db.any('SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE id = $1', [bar])
```

Would (in this case Postgres) tell that it is a character varying or text field and safely enter it into the database??  Or should we be sanitizing our data before sending it off to the stored procedure just to be safe?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what happens inside the function.

The only advantage of a function encapsulating dynamic SQL is that the types of the parameters will be checked, which makes dynamic SQL safe if none of the parameters are strings.

Other than that, you will have to use one of the usual constructs:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE id = %s', bar);
```

or

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE id = ' || quote_literal(bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to sanitize before using values in SP, at least for the string fields.

```
const bar = "1'; DROP TABLE users;"; 
db.any('SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE id = $1', [bar]
```

This scenario you mentioned will create SQL injection if `id` is a string.